# python regex search which not starts and ends with any of specified letters

Tags: python, regex

I want to find "foo" in a sentence which does not have any lowercase, uppercase characters, digits or underscore at the beginning and at the end of "foo".

For example, in `".foo bar (foo) bar foo-bar foo_bar foo'bar bar-foo bar, foo."` I want to find `".foo "` , `"(foo)"` , `" foo-"` , `" foo'"` , `"-foo "` , `" foo."`.

I tried to solve this problem by using this regex: `"(?![a-zA-Z0-9_])foo(?![a-zA-Z0-9_])"`; but it didn't work.

Comment: Look at negative lookahead/lookbehind :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `^` at the start of the character class:

```
>>> strs = ".foo bar (foo) bar foo-bar foo_bar foo'bar bar-foo bar, foo."
>>> re.findall('[^\w+]foo[^\w+]', strs)
['.foo ', '(foo)', ' foo-', " foo'", '-foo ', ' foo.']
```

Comment: @SaulloCastro: Yes it does; it works fine and as requested on that string.